# С помощью какой программы создаются makefil-ы для linux?

Tags: linux, makefile

С помощью какой программы создаются makefil-ы для linux?

Comment: текстовый редактор. либо генерятся с помощью automake, qmake, cmake и многих других.

Comment: Рученьками, рученьками и еще желательно через vi

Comment: Через emacs намного удобнее. Он синтаксис Makefile понимает (подсвечивает).

@ivan31, не поленитесь, изучите make. Это хороший язык программирования.

Comment: Как там?

     .PHONY: love
     love:
      @echo not war

Answer (score 6, accepted):

gedit, kate, nano, vim, emacs, Sublime text2, Eclipse etc.

Автоматическое создание - cmake. qmake

Comment: Еще есть устаревший `imake`

Answer (score 2):

Проще всего делать их при помощи системы сборки [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/). Но эта простота относительна, поскольку язык, который используется в ней для описания проекта, весьма своеобразен. По-настоящему просто станет лишь тогда, когда слегка к нему попривыкнешь.